How does one calculate the flight path angle during re-entry?
When the Apollo 11 spacecraft was on it's way onto the surface of the earth, it of course had to re-enter the atmosphere. Listening to the "Think Like a Rocket Scientist" book by Ozan Varol, it is said that the angle during re-entry should be "just right" and that it could result in an overshoot where the craft bounces off the atmosphere or it burns into a crisp. I would like to know what the factors are in order to calculate the perfect re-entry angle in order for a safe landing on the surface. And how these factors change depending on the spacecraft (such as for an Apollo command module to a Space Shuttle landing).

You're probably looking for the flight path angle, not the angle of attack.

okay changes made, thank you

See this answer https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49546/did-the-apollo-command-module-really-skip-within-or-off-of-the-atmosphere-as?rq=1 and follow links in the post to dig deeper into the rabbit hole

I really dislike the skip/bounce terminology. It looks like a bounce if you look at the altitude chart, but it's just a descent curve that's wider than the curvature of the earth. Or to put it another way, it's an aerobrake that wasn't strong enough to lower the apogee into the atmosphere. The capsule's momentum is not being halted and reversed the way a skipping rock does, it's just following its orbital path. It doesn't bounce off anything!

yes I understand that, but that's the only way I knew how to put it.

An Apollo capsule and the Space Shuttle had one very significant difference in their re-entry and that was their speeds. Space Shuttle was already in low earth orbit so basically any reduction in speed guaranteed a return to the Earth’s surface. The returning lunar flight had a much higher speed than that required to maintain a circular orbit around the Earth so if for any reason it hadn’t descend deep enough into the atmosphere to lose enough speed to be less than that required to for orbiting it would had just skimmed through the top layers of the atmosphere and then returned for an highly elliptical orbit. In such case the orbital time would have been more than what the lonely command module would have been able to sustain the three astronauts.
Once the spacecraft’s speed is reduced below orbital speed it will eventually sink deeper and deeper into the atmosphere. The rate at which the speed decays is dictated by the density of the air. As the craft descends to lower altitude it is subjected to higher drag and more heating. The descent rate is controlled by controlling the lift. The Space Shuttle did this by banking: the higher the bank angle the lesser the lift. The Apollo capsule was symmetrical but its center of gravity was purposely off-center so by rolling the vehicle they could direct the lift and thus control the descent rate.
